# Adding an XML attribute conditionally

Tags: scala

I need a way to add an XML attribute 'POSITON' to an XML element 'node' conditionally. Currently I'm doing the condition check first and then creating the node.

```
if (lvl == 2)
      node = <node COLOR={ color } CREATED={ epochTimeMillis } ID={ idGen } POSITION={ position } LINK={ link } MODIFIED={ epochTimeMillis } STYLE="bubble" TEXT={ f.getName() }>
               <edge COLOR={ color } STYLE={ style } WIDTH={ width }/>
             </node>
else
      node = <node COLOR={ color } CREATED={ epochTimeMillis } ID={ idGen } LINK={ link } MODIFIED={ epochTimeMillis } STYLE="bubble" TEXT={ f.getName() }>
               <edge COLOR={ color } STYLE={ style } WIDTH={ width }/>
             </node>
  }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using "null" is not a good practice, but in this case it would help you:

```
scala> <root ta={ if (true) "true" else null } fa={ if (false) "false" else null } />
res0: scala.xml.Elem = <root ta="true" ></root>
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked. I was earlier trying with "" but should have used null.

Answer (score 1):

A slightly cleaner way to do the same thing @senia suggests is:

```
    val posOpt = if (lvl2) Some(myPosition) else None
    val xml = <mydata position={posOpt orNull}/>
```

Answer (score 0):

One way is to create the snippet before:

```
val pos =
  if (lvl == 2) {
    "position = ..."
  } else {
    ""
  }
```

and to always insert it in the result.

This could by extended by using an *Option* with embedded *map* in combination with string interpolation.

```
val pos =
  if (lvl == 2) {
    Some(position)
  } else {
    None
  }
```

with

```
pos.map(v => s"position = $v")
```